# El media query no cambia los estilos en pantallas largas

Tags: css

tengo este codigo:

```
#game.row > .col {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
}


@media screen (min-width: 40.0rem) {
    #game.row > .col {
        width: 50%;
        height: 100vh !important;
        float: left;
        padding: 15px;
    }
}
```

Y al momento de que la pantalla es mayor a 40rem: 640px, no deja el alto en 100vh sino que lo mantiene en 50vh y al ver el inspector este no lo sobrescribe y queda en 50vh. No se que pasa.

Comment: Llego tarde a la fiesta, dos mejoras muy pequeñas al código: cuando se utiliza un id en el selector, no es necesario usar la clase que viene con este: `#game > .col`. Los decimales en 0 sobran `min-width: 40rem`, y asumiría que el `!important` ya no lo necesitas, al igual que el `float: left;` y el `padding: 15px`, los cuales al parecer son redundantes.

Comment: @Shaz Cierto! Muchas gracias por los consejos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La `@media` query es incorrecta. Le falta un `and` entre el tipo de dispositivo y la condición y por eso no funciona. Si haces lo siguiente:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 40.0rem) {
```

ya funcionará sin problemas como puedes ver aquí ([o en este JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/43qsyamt/)):

```css
#game.row > .col {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40.0rem) {
    #game.row > .col {
        width: 50%;
        height: 100vh !important;
        float: left;
        padding: 15px;
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="game" class="row">
    <td class="col">1</td>
    <td class="col">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Excelente, llevo horas con este problema.